# Inquiry on ROS melodic package compatibility with Naoqi OS 2.5.7.1

Tags: ros, nao-robot, pepper

**Problem Description**
I wish to use the ROS melodic packages developed for the pepper and nao robots. The Pepper currently uses Naoqi OS --version 2.5.7.1. I am worried about the compatibility of the OS version with the ROS melodic packages like `pepper_bringup` and so on.

**Inquiry**
I have not been able to find any resource online as of yet that discusses the compatibility issues and thought I'd ask on here.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing officially described about that compatibility. I believe it should be working but I have not tested it.
If there are issues with ROS `noetic`, you might probably get support from the maintainers.